# Floating DIV fit over another DIV

Tags: html, css

I need to get it so the div containing the date is at the top of the full_card div and expands to the full width of the card. Currently it is much lower and not expanding the full width.

```css
p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#container {
  width: full;
}

.full_card {
  float: left;
  background-color: #d1ccff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #404266;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
}

#event {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

#tag {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.date_back {
  background-color: #404266;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}

#date {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="full_card">
    <div class="date_back">
      <p id="date">1981</p>
    </div>
    <p id="event">Voldemort murders Lily and James Potter</p>
    <hr>
    <p id="tag">Harry Potter</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add margin-top: 0px; to your .date class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code to show you how this is done.

1. The `padding` on the `.full_card` element affected everything inside of it, including the purple date "tab". I commented out this padding so the tab wouldn't be pushed down and inward.
2. By default, `<p>` elements have `margin` on the top and bottom. You need to override this if you don't want it - I added `margin: 0;` to stop the `#date` element from moving down.
3. Since we removed padding in step 1 (`30px` from both sides), I added `60px` of width to the `.full_card` element to bring it to `210px` wide, and then added `30px` of padding to the sides inside the `#event` element.
4. To get the border-radius working properly on the purple element, I added `overflow: hidden` to `.full_card` (to "trim" anything inside to its shape), and removed the unneeded `border-radius` that was on the `.date_back` element.

Hope this helps!

```css
p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#container {
  width: full;
}

.full_card {
  float: left;
  background-color: #d1ccff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #404266;
  margin: 10px;
  /*padding: 10px 30px; */
  width: 210px; /* added 60px */
  height: 250px; 
  overflow: hidden; /* added this for radius */
}

#event {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
  padding: 0 30px; /* added this */
}

#tag {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.date_back {
  background-color: #404266;
  /* border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px; */
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
}

#date {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0; /* added this */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="full_card">
    <div class="date_back">
      <p id="date">1981</p>
    </div>
    <p id="event">Voldemort murders Lily and James Potter</p>
    <hr>
    <p id="tag">Harry Potter</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works **perfectly**! Thank you!
Would it be too much trouble to ask for the same thing with the "tag" id, but at the bottom of the card?

Comment: @Spencer Glad it helped! Please take a second to upvote and mark my solution as accepted (with the checkmark) so it can help others.

Comment: @Spencer Simply removing the `height` from the `.full_card` element will put the `#tag` element flush at the bottom.

Comment: I realize that, but the eventual presentation will be about a dozen of these cards on the screen. They'll run left-to-right then drop to the next line. Since these are supposed to represent actual playing cards I was hoping to have a standard size.

Comment: @Spencer That makes sense. In that case, I would add a hardcoded `height: 110px;` to the `#event` element to give all cards the same amount of room for the description text. This pushes down the `#tag` to the bottom.